# npm ERR! 404 Not Found: pinkie-promise

Tags: npm, ionic2

I'm trying to install Ionic Pro, and I am getting this error while pushing through live deploy..
Any help would be gladly appreciated

`npm install --quiet --no-optional`

`npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: pinkie@2.0.4 (node_modules/pinkie):`

`npm WARN 404 SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Not Found: pinkie@https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie/-/pinkie-2.0.4.tgz`

`npm ERR! code E404`

`npm ERR! 404 Not Found: pinkie-promise@https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie-promise/-/pinkie-promise-2.0.1.tgz`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`

`npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2018-01-06T18_55_47_426Z-debug.log`

`npm install --quiet --no-optional failed`

`Running after script...`

`$ run "clean-up"`

`Running Stage clean-up for Job: 5211838`

`ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little under a year ago, the package "leftpad" broke NPM builds all over the world because the author pulled it from the public repository.

The same is happening today, for "pinkie-promise". The author's NPM account (@floatdrop) was deleted, opening opportunities for malware in all the packages he's written.

Dependent builds include Ionic and (in my case) node-sass.

Resources:

- NPM issue: https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255
- Incident report: https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj
- pinkie-promise issue: https://github.com/floatdrop/pinkie-promise/issues/4
- Dependent packages: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/pinkie-promise
- All of @floatdrop's repositories: https://github.com/floatdrop?tab=repositories

Comment: Yep - being hit with this when trying to deploy a project with google cloud dependencies. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by installing pinkie-promise by pointing to their github repo.

`npm install https://github.com/floatdrop/pinkie-promise.git`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution to make project build work again

Since this dependency is not available on npm registry, 
one will have to do the following to make it work.

Follow these steps to make things work again.

1. `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. `rm -rf package-lock.json`
3. `npm i https://github.com/floatdrop/pinkie-promise.git`

> In the end you will see the output

*+ pinkie-promise@2.0.1*