# npm install returns no valid versions available for pinkie-promise

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to do a very simple "npm install" from one of the repos found from a tutorial found [here](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist)

The package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "react-playlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple react to-do list",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "npm run build",
  "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --
   hot --port 1234 --history-api-fallback"
 },
 "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "The Net Ninja",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

When I run "npm install", I get an error about "no valid versions available for pinkie-promise". I looked on npm, and it seems pinkie-promise is deprecated and removed. How do I remove it from my package.json if it doesn't even show up there?

Here is the npm log for this error (Only included the bit with the error):

```
1281 silly resolveWithNewModule commondir@1.0.1 checking installable status
1282 silly pacote range manifest for pkg-dir@^1.0.0 fetched in 3ms
1283 silly resolveWithNewModule pkg-dir@1.0.0 checking installable status
1284 silly pacote range manifest for find-up@^1.0.0 fetched in 2ms
1285 silly resolveWithNewModule find-up@1.1.2 checking installable status
1286 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for pinkie-promise@^2.0.0 No valid 
versions available for pinkie-promise
1287 silly pacote range manifest for path-exists@^2.0.0 fetched in 4ms
1288 silly resolveWithNewModule path-exists@2.1.0 checking installable status
1289 verbose type range
1290 verbose stack pinkie-promise: No valid versions available for pinkie-
promise
1290 verbose stack     at pickManifest 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/npm-pick-
manifest/index.js:19:11)
1290 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument 
1290 verbose stack     at tryCatcher 
 at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
1290 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
1290 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] 
(timers.js:733:5)
1291 verbose cwd /root/Desktop/LeagueSystemWebApp
1292 verbose Linux 4.4.0-104-generic
1293 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
1294 verbose node v9.2.1
1295 verbose npm  v5.5.1
1296 error code ENOVERSIONS
1297 error No valid versions available for pinkie-promise
1298 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic Pro build failed -> npm ERR! 404 Not Found: pinkie-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131111/ionic-pro-build-failed-npm-err-404-not-found-pinkie-promise)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A work around is to npm install pinkie-promise by pointing to their github repo.

`npm install https://github.com/floatdrop/pinkie-promise.git`

Comment: you'll need the `.git` extension. `npm install https://github.com/HwangKC/ilsap.git`. You can get the extension the same way you would clone the repo.

Comment: @JonLambson it's giving `undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/HwangKC/ilsap.git` error.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil - if you visit their github repo it looks like it has been taken down. It says... "Repository unavailable due to DMCA takedown.
This repository is currently disabled due to a DMCA takedown notice. We have disabled public access to the repository. The notice has been publicly posted."

Comment: @JonLambson I was making mistakes in previous commands due to which i get the above error, now my problem is solved

Answer (score 5):

It is not your mistake.

Official issue: https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255

Official status: https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj