# npm install fail because of pinkie dependency

Tags: electron

Good morning,
I try a very simple `npm install` on the electron quick start that I found on `https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start`

But it seems the pinkie module has been removed of npm, I get `No matching version found for pinkie-promise@2.0.2` 
Can I manually create node_modules folder and put pinkie folder inside manually

I have tried  and reinstalled with  `npm install -verbose --save pinkie-promise@2.0.2` but I get No matching version found for pinkie-promise@2.0.2
I don't understand to don't find more information on this problem that concern electron.
I think I don't have the good pinkie folder, if anyone have a version of electron can he send me pinkie folder.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it seem to be a duplicate with [npm install returns no valid versions available for pinkie-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131818/npm-install-returns-no-valid-versions-available-for-pinkie-promise)

so I just do `npm install https://github.com/floatdrop/pinkie-promise.git` and `npm install -verbose --save pinkie-promise@2.0.1` and it seems to install